# How to append to a select box in the WordPress customiser from an API call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, customization

I'm working on a WordPress theme and I've added a select box to allow users to select a font for their site. I figured I'd use the Google Fonts API to grab the list of fonts rather than add all 900-and-something manually, but when I call the API I'm unable to append the returned data as options in the select box.

This is the PHP code for my select box class:

```php
    class Customize_Select_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
        public $type = 'select';

        public function render_content() {
            ?>
            <label>
                <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
                <select <?php $this->link(); ?> id="<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower(esc_html( $this->label ))); ?>-select">
                    <option value="<?php echo $this->value(); ?>" selected><?php echo $this->value(); ?></option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

I've then added a section, setting and control to the customiser using the following code:

```
    // Add Font Section
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'fonts' , array(
        'title' => __( 'Font', 'wordpress' ),
        'priority' => 100,
        'description' => __( 'Pick a font for your website.', 'wordpress' )
    ) );

    // Add the setting & control for the font
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'font-select' , array(
        'default'   => 'Open Sans',
        'transport' => 'postMessage',
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new Customize_Select_Control( $wp_customize, 'font-select', array(
        'label'      => __( 'Font', 'wordpress' ),
        'section'    => 'fonts',
        'settings'   => 'font-select',
    ) ) );
```

The following code is supposed to append the options to the select box:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=[REDACTED]&sort=popularity&fields=items",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status, xhr){
          console.log(result.items);
          for (var i = 0; i<result.items.length; i++){
            var family = result.items[i].family;
            console.log(family);
            $('#font-select').append(`<option value="${family}">${family}</option>`);
          }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          alert("There was an error loading the Google fonts API: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n\nPlease save your changes and refresh the page to try again.")
        }
      });
```

If I change *#font-select* to *body*, it appends the options just fine, but however I try and append them to the select box, it just doesn't work. Any idea why and how I can make this work?

Answer (score 9):

You can add Option value in select box in customizer admin panel as by below code :

Full code of your requirements

- you just have to add your google font api key in scripts
- where I have used 'twentynineteen' theme slug name you can use your theme slug name

There are 3 parts:

```
1)  function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
        //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here


        $wp_customize->add_section( 'fonts' , array(
            'title' => __( 'Font', 'twentynineteen' ),
            'priority' => 100,
            'description' => __( 'Pick a font for your website.', 'twentynineteen' )
        ) );

        // Add the setting & control for the font
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'font-select' , array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'default' => 'Roboto',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control(  'font-select', array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'priority' => 10, // Within the section.
            'section' => 'core', // Required, core or custom.
            'description' => __( 'This is a date control with a red border.' ),
            'choices' => array( // Optional.
            'wordpress' => __( 'Roboto' ),
            'hamsters' => __( 'Lato' ),
            'jet-fuel' => __( 'Muli' ),

        ),
            'label'      => __( 'Font', 'twentynineteen' ),
            'section'    => 'fonts',
            'settings'   => 'font-select',
        )  );

     }
     add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

now add scripts file

```
2) function add_font_scripts(){

  wp_enqueue_script('custom_js_script', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/custom-scripts.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_font_scripts' );
```

now last step please add below script in this file custom-scripts.js which we just enqueue above

```
3)  var $= jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=apikey&sort=popularity&fields=items",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result, status, xhr){
            var outputstate = [];
          console.log(result.items);
          for (var i = 0; i<result.items.length; i++){
            var family = result.items[i].family;
            console.log(family);

           outputstate.push('<option value="'+ family +'">'+ family +'</option>');
           $('#_customize-input-font-select').html(outputstate.join(''));
          }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          alert("There was an error loading the Google fonts API: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n\nPlease save your changes and refresh the page to try again.")
        }


        });
    });
```

I have try this code and It's Working fine!

I Hope this one is help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @KrishnaSavani. I've tried to implement your code but it doesn't seem to work in my theme. It looks like you used it with the twentynineteen theme so I wonder if that might be why. I'm making my theme from scratch with [underscores](https://underscores.me/). Your code is still logging the fonts to the console, and appending the options to body html, but won't append the options to the font select box, even though I've double checked the IDs and they all match up.

Comment: I have tried as your way like get the theme from (https://underscores.me/) and it's also working fine there..now can you double check the select box id in customizer (https://prnt.sc/pfs2bn) it will be same as to add in jquery script..I have used 'font-select' while adding controls in customizer but when i am appending to jquery i am using this id ('#_customize-input-font-select"') so please can you check this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX Success Callback is looking for the dropdown with `id` as `font-select`. However, the id of the Dropdown is based on the Label (which happens to be `font`).

The ID of the dropdown is created by following line of code in `render_content` method.

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower(esc_html( $this->label ))); ?>
```

`$this->label` here will refer to the `Fonts`. Since you are using strtolower it will be `fonts`. I suggest you pass another variable for the `id` and populate it using that variable.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @ascsoftw, but the id of the select box is being rendered as `#font-select` (notice the `-select` after the code you mentioned). [Screenshot here](https://postimg.cc/VJVRrvpF). Initially I wasn't using the extra `-select` bit, but I added that as I thought it may be clashing with another ID somewhere.

Comment: ok, I see it now. Could you confirm that there is no other element with id "font-select"

Comment: Searching for `font-select` in the element inspector yields no results other than the select box in question. My only guess is that it's something to do with the fact that the customiser settings panel is dynamically generated. I'm also unable to render the data from the API call anywhere within the customiser panel, but rendering them within the html of the page preview works fine. I've tried using `setTimeout` and `ajaxComplete` to get around the issue but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Dynamically generating `font-select` should not prevent it from populating. Can you `console.log( $('#font-select').length);  ` as the first line in the success callback of AJAX  to make sure that the select box exists.

Comment: Good call, I didn't think to do that. The response is '0'. However, if I enter the same command directly into the dev tools console, it returns '1'.

Comment: That obviously means your Dropdown is being generated after the AJAX call. You will need to make sure it is generated before that AJAX Call is started.

Comment: I've just tried using a `setTimeout` with a 10 second delay, and the `console.log( $('#font-select').length);` still returns 0, even though I can physically see the element on the page. Entering `console.log( $('#font-select').length);` still returns 1. I also tried firing the the ajax call when the select box is clicked, but this did nothing.

Comment: Difficult for me to give any more input. Issue seems to be that select box is not present / visible during AJAX Call. Cann't figure out why.

Comment: No worries, I'm equally as confused! Thank you for your input all the same though :)